# Inactive buttons in Cheese on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, cheese

I upgraded to ubuntu 12.04 and now I get error messages in terminal when I run cheese. The program opens, but none of the buttons are active and preferences is not highlighted and can't be clicked on. Therefore I can't run my webcam anymore. It worked fine in older versions of ubuntu. Help!

The error message is:

> (cheese:2332): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a GtkButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkButton can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of current state of cheese.